# Como obtener el token de FireBaseMessaging antes que se llame la siguiente funcion?

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-messaging

Se supone que este método debería autenticarme en el servidor pasándole usuario, pass, y el token de FirebaseMessaging.

```
override suspend fun authUser(usuario: String, pass: String): Boolean {
    val firebaseToken = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().token.result!!
    val token = authUserDataSource.authUser(usuario, pass, firebaseToken)
    return if (token != null && !token.token.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        tokenDataSource.saveToken(token.toToken().toTokenEntity())
        true
    } else {
        false
    }
}
```

> E/MyApp/Log_In: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Task is not yet complete

El problema que estoy teniendo es que evidentemente llama al metodo **authUserDataSource.authUser(usuario,pass,firebaseToken)** antes de obtener el token de Firebase.

Intenté ejecutar el metodo **authUserDataSource.authUser(usuario,pass,firebaseToken)** dentro del onSuccessListener de esta manera:

```
val firebaseToken = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().token.addOnSuccessListener { val token = authUserDataSource.authUser(usuario, pass, firebaseToken) }
```

pero me dice que las **suspend fun** solo pueden ser llamadas dentro de un bloque de corrutina.

Alguien sabe como se puede solucionar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Efectivamente las *suspend functions* solo pueden ser llamadas dentro de un bloque de corrutina.

El código que muestras es un bloque de corrutina por ser parte de una suspend function pero este contexto se pierde dentro de los listeners que crees y por ello no puedes llamar a otras suspend functions.

Para integrar las corrutinas con APIs basadas en callbacks se suele crear un wrapper o adapter pero en tu caso no será necesario porque ya existe
[este](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/master/integration/kotlinx-coroutines-play-services) adapter que provee integración con la clase `Task` que es usada por todas las librerías de Google, incluidas las de Firebase.

Simplemente debes agregarlo como dependencia en el archivo `build.gradle`

```
implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-play-services:1.5.1")
```

y luego usar la función [await](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/integration/kotlinx-coroutines-play-services/src/Tasks.kt#L103) para esperar que se complete la tarea de obtener el token

```
val firebaseToken = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().token.await()!!
val token = authUserDataSource.authUser(usuario, pass, firebaseToken)
```

Cuando no exista un adapter para la API que quieras integrar, puedes seguir esta [guía](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/simplifying-apis-with-coroutines-and-flow-a6fb65338765) para crearlo tu mismo.

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciono perfecto. Desconocía de estos temas que me nombraste, ahora a ponerme a investigar. Saludos